# Cómo obtener nombres de tablas dinámicamente con datatable y Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable

tengo dos tablas y estoy usando múltiples tablas de datos.

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="card-box table-responsive">
            <table id="table1" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive table-hover" data-table="tableOne">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>First name</th>
                        <th>Last name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="card-box table-responsive">
            <table id="table2" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive table-hover" data-table="tableTwo">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>First name</th>
                        <th>Last name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Quiero enviar un parámetro que seria el idtable o el nombre de la tabla a través de ajax donde tengo el atributo para cada tabla `data-table` .

```js
$('table.table').DataTable({
        "autoWidth": false,
        "paging": true,
        "info": true,
        "responsive": true,
        "filter": true,
        ajax: {
            url: base_url+"controller/action",
            "type": "POST",
            data: function (d) {
                d.data = "data-table"; //id_table
            }
        },
        "stateSave": true,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
    });
```

En teoría debería funcionar así: `d.data = $(this).attr("data-table");` de forma dinámica, y su resultado sería algo así: `table1 = tableOne` y para `table2 = tableTwo` , pero no me funciona :(

A mí me Funciona así; `d.data = $('table.table').attr("data-table");` , pero la primera tabla se repite dos veces `table1 = tableOne` y `table2 = tableOne`, y de esa manera no me sirve para desarrollar.

Alguien me puede ayudar por favor, se lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: Maybe you didn't notice, but you're at SO en español, so please translate your question or it will be closed

Comment: Edison, veo que ya hiciste preguntas en español, en este sitio anteriormente. Posiblemente hayas notado que todo el sitio está en español. Por lo tanto las preguntas también deberían estar en español. Si quieres hacerlo en inglés ve a https://stackoverflow.com